# Angular 4 will not recognize certain images located in assets/images folder when using ng serve or npm start

Tags: angular, image, assets

I get 404 errors when running the localhost server for only certain images even though they are the same size and file type. It seems like Angular is not properly updating or recognizing some of my images.

Comment: Each time you add a new file, you will need to stop the `ng serve` with `ctrl + c`, and then rerun `ng serve`.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but I've tried that several times and it still doesn't update.

Comment: Maybe the images are trying to be loaded from the compiled production folder? Those images don't update until you do a prod command

Comment: Could you add your `angular.json` configuration file?

Comment: Hey, not sure what the issue is still. Currently trying to update to a newer version of Angular because this issue has occured a lot in the past and have never been able to fix it. I don't think its an issue with Angular.json because it does reference most images from the src/images directory. Haven't gotten to try building with prod command yet since I am in the process of updating but will let you know if that works out.

Comment: OK, updated npm, setup a new site from scratch that runs in Angular 6 instead of Angular 4. The same problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Open angular.json file which contains meta information about the projects.
there is a attribute called assets,its in a form of array, add your assets folder like this:

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/images"
        ],
```

Comment: I already have the "src/assets" in my angular.json file, from there it has a sub-directory "images". Most of these images show up however, some simply fail to be retrieved by the localhost Angular server ng serve.

Answer (score 0):

Jeeze, not sure why this was but for some reason files that originate from my computer do not show up, but files that are downloaded do. For instance one of my images was a snipped of a PCB I was working on. To fix this I had to submit it to a website (https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png) then download it back to my computer. After that I had no issues with the image. Note: the original image format was also a png.

Hope this helps someone else out.